# How create loading effect to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, loading

I need to display a loading indeterminate progress bar while receiving data in my fragment. How can I do this? I tried to use this sample code, but it didn't worked for me as expected.

[image]

Comment: ListFragment has already this functionality ... https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/c6182418fd1c387bf5b6 ... key method: `setListShown`

Comment: Can you provide the details as to what kind of data is going to get displayed and from where it would be fetched? Local database or JSON from Server?

Answer (score 0):

Define Interface having method called doPostExecute() in your data retrieving class say in an AsyncClass, call this **doPostExecute()** method when data is being retrieved.

Now implement this interface in your Fragment and run progress bar till this call back occurs

Answer (score 0):

Use the following if you want to have a spinning circle.

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        />
```